# Why the slider image the only thing that's not responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm using flexslider by woothemes, and cannot figure out why the image is continually way wider than the content when the browser is resized/site is viewed on an ipad/iphone.

I don't see any styles on the slider, slide OR image that could be causing the image to not resize. There is no height or width attribute set on the actual image itself. Furthermore, there is only one image in the slider.

The container for the content seems to be resizing too, and the image/slide width is set to 100% but still overflowing to the right hand side, causing a horizontal scroll to appear.

site: http://whitakerbespoke.com/

EDIT: The image now resizes, but there is still a horizontal scroll bar, and a huge empty space on the right hand side. I figured the image was causing this, but it doesn't seem that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `width: 100%` to the `.flexslider .slides img` css declaration, so it looks like this (line 21 of flexslider.css):

```
.flexslider .slides img {margin: 0 auto; display: block; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: woah, nice! why didn't i think of this sooner. there is still a huge space on the right hand side. what is the cause of this, if not the image??

Comment: Also, line 25 of `skeleton.css` is setting the width of `#footer .container` to 960px, causing it to stick out on the right side. One trick I use to identify problems like that is to add `div {border:1px solid #000 !important;}`.

Comment: @showdev ahhhh nice!!! dont know how on earth i couldn't figure all this out, but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width: 100%` to the `img` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

easy :
http://whitakerbespoke.com/wp-content/themes/spacing/css/skeleton-responsive.css?ver=3.5.1
line 28

```
#footer .container {
    width: 960px;
}
```

You need to make this box flexible ... like 'width:100%';

carry on